# Need help troubleshooting RSpec controller test with Nested Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

To learn Rails and testing, I'm building a Rails 4 application using RSpec (v.3.1.0), Capybara(2.4.3) and FactoryGirl.  In routes.rb, I nested the following resource to reflect the association between models:

```
resources :members do
  resources :cardio_exercises
end
```

members.rb contains:
     has_many :cardio_exercises, :dependent => :destroy

cardio_exercises.rb contains:
     belongs_to :member

The FactoryGirl factory for cardio_exercises contains
    association :member

After nesting the resource, I made necessary changes to the views and cardio_exercises_controller.rb:

```
class CardioExercisesController < ApplicationController

# :get_member is defined in the private method at the bottom of this file,
# and takes the member_id provided by the routing and
#converts it to a @member object.

before_action :get_member    

# GET member/1/cardio_exercises
# GET member/1/cardio_exercises.json
def index
  @cardio_exercises = @member.cardio_exercises
end

# GET member/1/cardio_exercises/1
# GET member/1/cardio_exercises/1.json
def show
  @cardio_exercise = @member.cardio_exercises.find(params[:id])
end

# GET member/1/cardio_exercises/new
def new
  @member = Member.find(params[:member_id])
  @cardio_exercise = @member.cardio_exercises.build
end

# GET member/1/cardio_exercises/1/edit
def edit
  @cardio_exercise = @member.cardio_exercises.find(params[:id])
end

# POST member/1/cardio_exercises
# POST member/1/cardio_exercises.json
def create
  @cardio_exercise = @member.cardio_exercises.build(cardio_exercise_params)

  if @cardio_exercise.save
    flash[:success] = "Cardio exercise was successfully created."
    redirect_to member_cardio_exercises_path(@member)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end  

# PATCH/PUT member/1/cardio_exercises/1
# PATCH/PUT member/1/cardio_exercises/1.json
def update
  @cardio_exercise = @member.cardio_exercises.find(params[:id])
  if @cardio_exercise.update(cardio_exercise_params)
    flash[:success] = "Cardio exercise was successfully updated."
    redirect_to member_cardio_exercises_path(@member)
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

# DELETE member/1/cardio_exercises/1
# DELETE member/1/cardio_exercises/1.json
def destroy
  @cardio_exercise = @member.cardio_exercises.find(params[:id])
  @cardio_exercise.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to (member_cardio_exercises_path(@member)), notice: 'Cardio exercise was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
 end


private
  # The get_member action converts the member_id given by the routing
  # into an @member object, for use here and in the view.

  def get_member
    @member = Member.find(params[:member_id])
  end


  def cardio_exercise_params
    params.require(:cardio_exercise).permit(:title, :duration, :calories_burned, :date, :member_id)
  end
end
```

I updated my RSpec routing tests successfully with the help of rake routes:

```
                 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                             Controller#Action
                   root GET    /                                                       static_pages#home
                  about GET    /about(.:format)                                        static_pages#about
                   help GET    /help(.:format)                                         static_pages#help
                contact GET    /contact(.:format)                                      static_pages#contact
                 signup GET    /signup(.:format)                                       users#new
                  login GET    /login(.:format)                                        sessions#new
                        POST   /login(.:format)                                        sessions#create
                 logout DELETE /logout(.:format)                                       sessions#destroy
                  users GET    /users(.:format)                                        users#index
                        POST   /users(.:format)                                        users#create
               new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                                    users#new
              edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                               users#edit
                   user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                    users#show
                        PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                                    users#update
                        PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                    users#update
                        DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                                    users#destroy
member_cardio_exercises GET    /members/:member_id/cardio_exercises(.:format)          cardio_exercises#index
                        POST   /members/:member_id/cardio_exercises(.:format)          cardio_exercises#create
new_member_cardio_exercise GET    /members/:member_id/cardio_exercises/new(.:format)      cardio_exercises#new
edit_member_cardio_exercise GET    /members/:member_id/cardio_exercises/:id/edit(.:format) cardio_exercises#edit
 member_cardio_exercise GET    /members/:member_id/cardio_exercises/:id(.:format)      cardio_exercises#show
                        PATCH  /members/:member_id/cardio_exercises/:id(.:format)      cardio_exercises#update
                        PUT    /members/:member_id/cardio_exercises/:id(.:format)      cardio_exercises#update
                        DELETE /members/:member_id/cardio_exercises/:id(.:format)      cardio_exercises#destroy
                members GET    /members(.:format)                                      members#index
                        POST   /members(.:format)                                      members#create
             new_member GET    /members/new(.:format)                                  members#new
            edit_member GET    /members/:id/edit(.:format)                             members#edit
                 member GET    /members/:id(.:format)                                  members#show
                        PATCH  /members/:id(.:format)                                  members#update
                        PUT    /members/:id(.:format)                                  members#update
                        DELETE /members/:id(.:format)                                  members#destroy
               trainers GET    /trainers(.:format)                                     trainers#index
                        POST   /trainers(.:format)                                     trainers#create
            new_trainer GET    /trainers/new(.:format)                                 trainers#new
           edit_trainer GET    /trainers/:id/edit(.:format)                            trainers#edit
                trainer GET    /trainers/:id(.:format)                                 trainers#show
                        PATCH  /trainers/:id(.:format)                                 trainers#update
                        PUT    /trainers/:id(.:format)                                 trainers#update
                        DELETE /trainers/:id(.:format)                                 trainers#destroy
     strength_exercises GET    /strength_exercises(.:format)                           strength_exercises#index
                        POST   /strength_exercises(.:format)                           strength_exercises#create
  new_strength_exercise GET    /strength_exercises/new(.:format)                       strength_exercises#new
 edit_strength_exercise GET    /strength_exercises/:id/edit(.:format)                  strength_exercises#edit
      strength_exercise GET    /strength_exercises/:id(.:format)                       strength_exercises#show
                        PATCH  /strength_exercises/:id(.:format)                       strength_exercises#update
                        PUT    /strength_exercises/:id(.:format)                       strength_exercises#update
                        DELETE /strength_exercises/:id(.:format)                       strength_exercises#destroy
           appointments GET    /appointments(.:format)                                 appointments#index
                        POST   /appointments(.:format)                                 appointments#create
        new_appointment GET    /appointments/new(.:format)                             appointments#new
       edit_appointment GET    /appointments/:id/edit(.:format)                        appointments#edit
            appointment GET    /appointments/:id(.:format)                             appointments#show
                        PATCH  /appointments/:id(.:format)                             appointments#update
                        PUT    /appointments/:id(.:format)                             appointments#update
                        DELETE /appointments/:id(.:format)                             appointments#destroy
```

I'm struggling to write tests of the controller for the nested resource.  Currently, tests of "GET index" and (the first it) of "POST create" are passing; the other tests are failing.  My cardio_exercises_controller_spec.rb is incomplete, but here's what I have so far:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe CardioExercisesController, :type => :controller do
before :each do
  @member = FactoryGirl.create(:member)
  @cardio_exercise = FactoryGirl.create(:cardio_exercise)
  @cardio_exercise_attributes = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:cardio_exercise, :member_id => @member)
end

describe "GET index" do
  it "assigns all cardio_exercises as @member.cardio_exercises" do     
    get :index, { :member_id => @member  }
    expect(assigns(:cardio_exercises)).to eq(@member.cardio_exercises)
  end
end

describe "GET show" do
  it "assigns the requested cardio_exercise as @member.cardio_exercise" do
    #@cardio_exercise = @member.cardio_exercises.find(params[:id])      
    get :show, { :member_id => @member, :cardio_exercise_id => @cardio_exercise }
    expect(assigns(:cardio_exercise)).to eq(@member.cardio_exercise)
  end
end 

describe "GET new" do
  it "assigns a new cardio_exercise as @member.cardio_exercise" do
    get :new, { :member_id => @member }
    expect(assigns(:cardio_exercise)).to be_a_new(@member.cardio_exercise)
  end
end

describe "GET edit" do
  xit "assigns the requested cardio_exercise as @member.cardio_exercise" do 
  end
end

describe "POST create" do
  describe "with valid params" do
    it "creates a new CardioExercise" do
      expect {
                  post :create, { :member_id => @member, :cardio_exercise => @cardio_exercise_attributes }
      }.to change(CardioExercise, :count).by(1)         
    end

    xit "assigns a newly created cardio_exercise as @cardio_exercise" do
    end

    xit "redirects to the created cardio_exercise" do
    end
  end
end

describe "PUT update" do
    describe "with invalid params" do

    xit "updates the requested cardio_exercise" do

   end

   xit "assigns the requested cardio_exercise as @member.cardio_exercise" do

   end

    xit "redirects to the cardio_exercise" do
   end
  end

  describe "with invalid params" do
    xit "assigns the cardio_exercise as @member.cardio_exercise" do

  end

  xit "re-renders the 'edit' template" do

    expect(response).to render_template("edit")
    end
  end
end

describe "DELETE destroy" do
  it "destroys the requested cardio_exercise" do
    expect {
      delete :destroy, { :member_id => @member, :cardio_exercise_id => @cardio_exercise }
    }.to change(CardioExercise, :count).by(-1)
  end

  it "redirects to the cardio_exercises list" do      
    delete :destroy, { :member_id => @member, :cardio_exercise_id => @cardio_exercise }
    expect(response).to redirect_to(member_cardio_exercises_url)
  end
 end
end
```

Running the spec generates no route matching and undefined method errors:

```
1) CardioExercisesController GET show assigns the requested cardio_exercise as @member.cardio_exercise
 Failure/Error: get :show, { :member_id => @member, :cardio_exercise_id => @cardio_exercise }
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"show", :cardio_exercise_id=>"15", :controller=>"cardio_exercises", :member_id=>"29"}

2) CardioExercisesController GET new assigns a new cardio_exercise as @member.cardio_exercise
 Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:cardio_exercise)).to be_a_new(@member.cardio_exercise)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `cardio_exercise' for #<Member:0x00000009aaa628>

3) CardioExercisesController DELETE destroy destroys the requested cardio_exercise
 Failure/Error: delete :destroy, { :member_id => @member, :cardio_exercise_id => @cardio_exercise }
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :cardio_exercise_id=>"18", :controller=>"cardio_exercises", :member_id=>"35"}

 4) CardioExercisesController DELETE destroy redirects to the cardio_exercises list
 Failure/Error: delete :destroy, { :member_id => @member, :cardio_exercise_id => @cardio_exercise }
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :cardio_exercise_id=>"19", :controller=>"cardio_exercises", :member_id=>"37"}
```

The nested route and related view code work as expected in my application.  Obviously, I'm failing to give RSpec all the information it needs to test my controller. I understand that I must pass ids for some tests, but I'm confused about the syntax. During my research, I found numerous posts that discussed the issue, but nothing that I could use to solve it.

How do I change my controller tests to give RSpec the information it needs?  I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors 1, 3 and 4 are due to the fact that you're RSpec example is setting the parameter `:cardio_exercise_id` rather than the required (per your routes) `:id`. Your passing examples are working because they don't require this parameter.

Error 2 is due to the fact that `has_many` doesn't define a singular access method for the association (i.e. `member.cardio_exercises` is defined, but not `member.cardio_exercise`). Since `be_a_new` just expects a class, you can simply pass `CardioExercise` as the parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  At my earliest opportunity,  I will try changing my controller spec,  and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Peter, thanks!  Error 2 is fixed; passing CardioExercise as the parameter solved it.  Unfortunately, I'm still stuck on Errors 1,3 and 4.  When I pass ":id => @cardio_exercise" it causes a Record Not Found error: "Couldn't find CardioExercise with 'id'=130 [WHERE "cardio_exercises"."member_id" = $1]". I've got to do more research. I don't know why the record can't be found or why member_id = $1.

Comment: Since this question has already been answered and your new problems amount to a different set of conditions/symptoms, you should really submit a separate question.

That said, the problem you're facing now is that you have not associated the cardio exercises with the member in your test setup, so `@member.cardio_exercises` will always return the empty set in your controller.